# Passing data from another class to another's class onPressed Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, variables

I'm trying to pass a data from class A to another class B. Class B would accept it and pass the data to Screen C through onPressed(in class B).

Below is how I pass and retrieve the data. Currently, my output in Screen C is 'null', it should display the data from class A

- Passing data from class A

```
class SelectAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectAccountState createState() => _SelectAccountState();
}

class _SelectAccountState extends State<SelectAccount> {

  var dropdownValue = 'one';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 375.0, height: 100.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 12.0, left: 12.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  itemHeight: 120,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Saving Account',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10.0,
                                      color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        RichText(
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                            text: '56,302.56',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                            ),
                                            children: <TextSpan>[
                                              TextSpan(
                                                text: ' THB',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      value: 'one',
                    ),
                    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'Saving Account 2',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Savings XXX-X-XX563-9',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 10.0,
                                      color: Colors.grey[900],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        RichText(
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                            text: '89,302.56',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                            ),
                                            children: <TextSpan>[
                                              TextSpan(
                                                text: ' THB',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      value: 'two',
                    ),
                    //DropdownMenuItem<String>(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PassAccount {

  static String dropdownValue;

}
```

- Accepting data in class B

```
class ToContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final PassAccount dropdownValue;

  ToContainer({Key key, this.dropdownValue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToContainerState createState() => _ToContainerState();
}
```

- Passing the accepted data from class B through onPressed() to Screen C

```
class _ToContainerState extends State<ToContainer> {

  var AccountSelected = PassAccount.dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: CupertinoButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Next',
                            style: style.clickButton,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  new DirectedScreen(
                                      value: PassData(
                                account: AccountSelected,
                              )),
                            );
                            Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue[600],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
                          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class PassData {

  final String account;

  const PassData(
      {
        this.account}
      );
}
```

- Display data in Screen C

```
class DirectedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final PassData value;

  DirectedScreen({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DirectedScreenState createState() => _DirectedScreenState();
}

class _DirectedScreenState extends State<DirectedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transfer Summary'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                child: new Text(
                  'PASSED VALUES',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                child: new Text(
                  'Bank : ${widget.value.account}',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advanced for the help !

Comment: Because the ```dropdownvalue``` isn't set?

Comment: @BillionShiferaw it actually is. the dropdownValue is a value of the item selected from a drop down menu. I have edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass data from B to Screen C by using [arguments](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments). You can check the guide for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Dont create separate data classes for each widget. Instead use the existing one only. Use `widget.dropdownValue` to use a parameter in the state class which is defined in the stateful widget class. See the below code:

```
onPressed: () {
  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
        new DirectedScreen(value: widget.dropdownValue),
  );
  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
},
```

and in `DirectedScreen` use `PassAccount` only to catch the value.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm using a separate class because the value of 'dropdownValue' is from a dropdownmenu item. The code is quite long, that's why I separate it. Do you think it is better to compile them into a single class as you suggested ?

Comment: Yes, it is good to have all the data classes separate and reuse each class wherever possible

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to move `var AccountSelected = PassAccount.dropdownValue;` to `build`

code snippet

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var AccountSelected = PassAccount.dropdownValue;
    return Container(
```

working demo, init with 456, after click floating action button change to 789

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PassAccount {
  static String dropdownValue;
}

class ToContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final PassAccount dropdownValue;

  ToContainer({Key key, this.dropdownValue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToContainerState createState() => _ToContainerState();
}

class _ToContainerState extends State<ToContainer> {
  //var AccountSelected = PassAccount.dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var AccountSelected = PassAccount.dropdownValue;
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: CupertinoButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Next',
                            //style: style.clickButton,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  new DirectedScreen(
                                      value: PassData(
                                account: AccountSelected,
                              )),
                            );
                            Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue[600],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
                          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PassData {
  final String account;

  const PassData({this.account});
}

class DirectedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final PassData value;

  DirectedScreen({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DirectedScreenState createState() => _DirectedScreenState();
}

class _DirectedScreenState extends State<DirectedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transfer Summary'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                child: new Text(
                  'PASSED VALUES',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
              ),
              Padding(
                child: new Text(
                  'Bank : ${widget.value.account}',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    PassAccount.dropdownValue = "456";
    super.initState();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    PassAccount.dropdownValue = "789";
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ToContainer(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. based on your code, the value of bank is hard-coded, right. my dropdownValue is actually a value from an item of a dropdownmenu. Do you think I can still work around the code ? thanks !

Comment: It will work fine. after get dropdown value. just set PassAccount.dropdownValue = "yourvalue". just like click Floating Action Button and change value.

Comment: The AccountSelected is a fixed value in your original code.

Comment: Actually you do not need AccountSelected. you can directly use DirectedScreen(value: PassData(account: PassAccount.dropdownValue

Comment: may I know why I don't need AccountSelected ? Because, dropdownValue is passed when the button is clicked.

Comment: Dart support global variable, any variable declare outside class will become global. so you do not even need to pass parameter if you want.

Comment: So I declare both PassAcount and PassData globally ? both in their respective class ? Am I right ?

Comment: PassData is a class. You need to declare a varaible PassData passData; outside all class, and passData is a global variable.

Comment: PassAccount has a static dropdownValue and you can access static variable just like global variable.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion on not using AccountSelected. I got an error 
'The getter 'dropdownValue' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: dropdownValue'

Comment: Can't reproduce in my example. please post your full code.